# Desire2Learn:How to download a file from news attachment?

Tags: ios, desire2learn

I'm integrating desire2Learn in IOS. 
Please find the News object below:

```
{
        Attachments =         (

                        {
                FileId = 401485;
                FileName = "iOS Simulator Screen shot 04-Apr-2013 4.09.48 PM.png";
                Size = 171857;
            }
        );
        Body =         {
            Html = "<p>Audio and file</p>
\n<p></p>";
            Text = "Audio and file
\n";
        };
        EndDate = "<null>";
        Id = 43905;
        IsGlobal = 0;
        IsHidden = 0;
        IsPublished = 1;
        ShowOnlyInCourseOfferings = 0;
        StartDate = "2013-04-04T10:38:00.000Z";
        Title = "Audio and File attachment";
    }
```

I want to download the file. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the attachment for a news item, you use the [route that fetches the attachment by file ID](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/news.html#get--d2l-api-le-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-%28D2LID-orgUnitId%29-news-%28D2LID-newsItemId%29-attachments-%28D2LID-fileId%29). This route should return a file stream containing the file attachment data for the file identified with your provided ID. In your case, the file ID seems like it would be `401485`.